# After doing a sparse checkout with the immediate children option, can I retrieve a subfolder's contents in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn

My repository looks like this:

```
trunk
 doc
 src
 etc...
```

I want to grab the entire contents of src and get the other directories as needed in the future.

If I do a sparse checkout of trunk with "Just this item", I can get all of src by going into the Repo-Browser per the [TortoiseSVN documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html) (under the section "Checkout Depth".

Is there a way to get the entire contents of src at a later time if my sparse checkout is "Immediate children, including folders"?

It just seems a little awkward to me that if you use "immediate children" that you can never lazy load the entire contents of a folder, so I figured there was a way to do it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change the checkout depth by using the "update to revision" command (usually in the TSVN submenu, not in the top explorer context menu).
In that dialog, just select the depth you want, then hit the OK button to run the update.

Comment: But do I understand correctly that if I check out trunk with "immediate children", I would have to highlight every item beneath src in the repo browser and do "update to revision"?

BTW, thanks so much for making Tortoise.  It's incredibly useful and so well-made.

Comment: If you want to change the depth of only a few items and not all, then you can select all those items in explorer, right-click and choose "update to revision" - the update will then be done on each of those selected items. If you want to change the depth of all items, you can update-to-revision on the parent folder.